# Problems with Chronometer and ViewModel

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Pressing the button changes the `chronometerStateLData` and the `Chronometer` starts, after turning the screen `Observer` executes the code again, but the `Chronometer` does not start.

```
viewModel.chronometerStateLData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            Utils.setSettingChronometer(binding.timerRecord)
            binding.timerRecord.start()
        })
```

```
 public static void setSettingChronometer(Chronometer chronometer) {
        chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(chronometer1 -> {
            long time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer1.getBase();
            int h = (int) (time / 3600000);
            int m = (int) (time - h * 3600000) / 60000;
            int s = (int) (time - h * 3600000 - m * 60000) / 1000;
            String t = (h < 10 ? "0" + h : h) + ":" + (m < 10 ? "0" + m : m) + ":" + (s < 10 ? "0" + s : s);
            chronometer1.setText(t);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you don't use the [tag:android-studio] tag issues not related to Android Studio.

Comment: Yes, this problem does not concern Android Studio, I will be more careful when writing questions

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I didn't check `if (savedInstanceState == null)` when I created my fragment, so every time I flipped the screen a new fragment was created.